# How to change background in webview

Tags: android, webview, background-color

I have created two themes for my activity; Bright/Dark. But when i trigger change in theme, color of webpage loaded in the webview doesn't change.

I have tried this `myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`
but it doesn't make any difference. So, how would i go about this?

Here is my layout please have a look;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">   

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:night="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        night:night_background="@color/colorPrimary_n"
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/greenprogress"
            />

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <WebView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/webViewTop"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                night:night_background="@color/colorPrimary_n"
                android:layout_below="@id/progressBar3"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after searching around, i found out that, to change the color of webpage after it has loaded, CSS customization is needed, no settings in webview can make webpage transparent(at least in my case).

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it programmatically like below

```
webView.getSettings();
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

I think you should go with layer type too

mWebView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

GOOD LUCK:)

Comment: what webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); does that, it initially makes webview transparent, and in the start of the activity i can see my theme color, but after webpage starts to load it disappears, and color of webpage take places.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in java

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this code in xml:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/MyWebView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

and after this you just go to Java code and write this before loadUrl :

```
yourWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. Before loading of webpage, it remains transparent, but as soon as it loads, it acquires the colors of webpage

Comment: At least try to test it yourself first because WebView does not allowed background at all.